# How to connect relation between 2 google cloud sql table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Now I create Google app maker and then I create 2 table by google cloud sql.

- Data 1. Information table have id(Primary Key), E_ID, JoinDate
- Data 2. Position table have E_ID, positionName

I want to link table 1 and table 2 by E_ID. How can I connect relation for 2 table and display in one page.

[image]

[image]
This is a sample template. E_ID,Join_Date from information data and PositionId from position data.

Could you suggest me to config this and thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, having the two Cloud SQL models created, now to create the relation, please follow the instructions in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations#create_and_edit_relations), it should direct you in the steps of creating a relation between models. Do keep in mind that that page specifies:

> You can create relations only between Cloud SQL models.

Hope this is of assistance!